# Apache configuration for silent rewrite of query strings like codeigniter

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, querystring

Codeigniter rewrites query strings like the following:

`http://somedomain.com/index.php?q=something`

to become:

`http://somedomain.com/index.php/q/something`

I'd like to imitate this behavior on a (very) lightweight website I am developing for a wedding RSVP system. I don't want the bloat of codeigniter, nor do I need anything else that it provides. The only thing I'd like is this.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to setup a mod-rewrite rule that accomplishes this. I can setup a rule that translates `/q/something` into `?q=something`, but I can't get one that does that without changing the URL the user is viewing.

I'm basically looking for something that is, in effect, a "silent" version of the rewrite. That is, I want something that rewrites `q/something` to `?q=something`, but leaves the user's URL in their address bar as `q/something`.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

In the .htaccess file for the site, I have the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/index.php/q/(.*) /index.php?q=$1
```

In the basic configuration for the site (/etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.conf), I have:

```
<VirtualHost *>
        ServerAdmin me@email.com
        ServerName www.mysite.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/www.mysite.com
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
</VirtualHost>
```

The index.php file is currently simply printing out the value of `$_GET['q']`. Now, when I visit the site `http://www.mysite.com/index.php?q=12345`, it displays "12345" as expected. But, when I navigate to `http://www.mysite.com/index.php/q/12345`, it doesn't display anything. Or, rather, it appears that the value for the query string is empty. I'm not quite sure what I'm doing incorrectly.

Comment: Can you show us an actual configuration?  For the example here, `RewriteRule ^/index.php/q/(.*) /index.php?q=$1` seems to do exactly what you want...the client requests `/index.php/q/something`, the backend sees `index.php?q=something`, but there is no client redirect so nothing changes the URL visible to the client.

Comment: It sounds like your configuration is redirecting, instead of rewriting. Check that you've configured it to simply rewrite internally.

Comment: I edited the post to contain the information requested. I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I think your rewrite is fine, the problem is probably in your PHP.  You need to be parsing the URL, as `q/12345` has nothing in `$_GET`.  `$_GET` is specifically, `/?q=12345`.  Why don't you  `print_r($_REQUEST)` instead to see what I mean.  Also, do `print_r($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])`.

Comment: If the rewrite is in .htaccess, I think you'll want to take off the leading '/' in the RewriteRule pattern match.